# How to get handle to a specific XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

Consider you have the following xml structure:

```
<root>
  <File> a.txt 
      <Version> 1.5 </Version>
  </File>

  <File> b.txt 
      <Version> 1.0 </Version>
  </File>
</root>
```

How can I get a handle to the `XElement`:
`<Version> 1.0 </Version>` by search?
I know I can search by  tag with function `XElement.element(Xname)`
but this will not help me.

Comment: `but this will not help me` Why? your question is not clear.

Comment: `get a handle!` what are you trying to **get**? please be clear with your question!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a list of version's..Here it is!

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(yourXML);
List<string> lst=doc.Descendants()
                    .Elements("Version")
                    .Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, so I will answer it as far as I understand

If you want to get the list of `Version`s then this code is enough

```
var versions = xDoc.Descendants("Version").ToList();
```

If you want to extract other info from your xml then

```
var files = xDoc.Descendants("File")
                .Select(f => new
                {
                    File = f.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value.Trim(),
                    Version = f.Element("Version").Value.Trim()
                })
                .ToList();
```

The tricky part is getting the filename such as `b.txt` since the *XElement* `File`'s *value* contains also the value of its child (`Version`)